# Faster alternative to perform pandas groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with name (person_name), day and color (shirt_color) as columns.

Each person wears a shirt with a certain color on a particular day. The number of days can be arbitrary.

E.g. input:

```
name  day  color
----------------
John   1   White
John   2   White
John   3   Blue
John   4   Blue
John   5   White
Tom    2   White
Tom    3   Blue
Tom    4   Blue
Tom    5   Black
Jerry  1   Black
Jerry  2   Black
Jerry  4   Black
Jerry  5   White
```

I need to find the most frequently used color by each person.

E.g. result:

```
name    color
-------------
Jerry   Black
John    White
Tom     Blue
```

I am performing the following operation to get the results, which works fine but is quite slow:

```
most_frquent_list = [[name, group.color.mode()[0]] 
                        for name, group in data.groupby('name')]
most_frquent_df = pd.DataFrame(most_frquent_list, columns=['name', 'color'])
```

Now suppose I have a dataset with 5 million unique names. What is the best/fastest way to perform the above operation?

Comment: I hope someone will make a benchmark of all of these submissions. I'd do it now, but it is late here.

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen I'll add benchmarking comments to each solution.

Comment: 1.91 ms ± 2.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Numpy's `numpy.add.at` and `pandas.factorize`

This is intended to be fast.  However, I tried to organize it to be readable as well.

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.name)
j, c = pd.factorize(df.color)
n, m = len(r), len(c)

b = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.int64)

np.add.at(b, (i, j), 1)
pd.Series(c[b.argmax(1)], r)

John     White
Tom       Blue
Jerry    Black
dtype: object
```

---

### `groupby`, `size`, and `idxmax`

```
df.groupby(['name', 'color']).size().unstack().idxmax(1)

name
Jerry    Black
John     White
Tom       Blue
dtype: object

name
Jerry    Black
John     White
Tom       Blue
Name: color, dtype: object
```

---

### `Counter`

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

```
from collections import Counter

df.groupby('name').color.apply(lambda c: Counter(c).most_common(1)[0][0])

name
Jerry    Black
John     White
Tom       Blue
Name: color, dtype: object
```

Comment: 1st: 362 µs ± 1.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: 2nd: 1.51 ms ± 4.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: 3rd: 834 µs ± 2.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

It must be hard to beat this (~10 times faster on the sample daraframe than any proposed pandas solution and 1.5 faster than the proposed numpy solution). The gist is to stay away from pandas and use `itertools.groupby` which is doing a much better job when it concerns non-numerical data.

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

pd.Series({x: Counter(z[-1] for z in y).most_common(1)[0][0] for x,y 
          in groupby(sorted(df.values.tolist()), 
                            key=lambda x: x[0])})
# Jerry    Black
# John     White
# Tom       Blue
```

**Old Answer**

Here's another method. It is actually slower than the original one, but I'll keep it here:

```
data.groupby('name')['color']\
    .apply(pd.Series.value_counts)\
    .unstack().idxmax(axis=1)
# name
# Jerry    Black
# John     White
# Tom       Blue
```

Comment: Hah! I just did that.  I'll delete

Comment: @piRSquared C'mon, keep it! Let the OP decide.

Comment: @piRSquared Yours `Counter` was still on the slower side because of `apply`. The point here is not to mess up with pandas.

Comment: I think the `collections` solution is fine, but calling it 10x faster than pandas/numpy is misleading.  On a dataframe with even just a couple hundred rows, piRSquared's factorize solution beats it easily, and timings on a sample dataframe never mean much

Comment: @user3483203 Agree. I added a note that the 10x speedup is seen only on the sample dataframe.

Comment: 1st: 252 µs ± 1.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: 2nd: 3.65 ms ± 26.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Answer (score 5):

Solution from **`pd.Series.mode`**

```
df.groupby('name').color.apply(pd.Series.mode).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
Out[281]: 
name
Jerry    Black
John     White
Tom       Blue
Name: color, dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry I miss understanding the question and fixed .

Comment: 1.66 ms ± 3.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 2):

How about doing two groupings with `transform(max)`?

```
df = df.groupby(["name", "color"], as_index=False, sort=False).count()
idx = df.groupby("name", sort=False).transform(max)["day"] == df["day"]
df = df[idx][["name", "color"]].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    name  color
0   John  White
1    Tom   Blue
2  Jerry  Black
```

Comment: 12.2 ms ± 48.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Thank you. Not very good then, from what I see the others are getting. As feedback on time testing, if you're looping over the same small dataset many times it might not be comparable to doing it once on a large dataset. Many solutions like this have high startup cost, but will perform well as soon as it starts processing. Looping over the a small dataset many times means you might just be measuring the startup cost, which should be just a one time cost. I suggest you increase the size of the data set you are testing until it takes a few seconds to run one loop.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @piRSquared's `pd.factorize` and `np.add.at` ans.

We encode the stings in columns using

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.name)
j, c = pd.factorize(df.color)
n, m = len(r), len(c)
b = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.int64)
```

But then, instead of doing this:

```
np.add.at(b, (i, j), 1)
max_columns_after_add_at = b.argmax(1)
```

We get the `max_columns_after_add_at` using a jited function, to do add at and find maximum in the same loop:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def add_at(x, rows, cols, val):
    max_vals = np.zeros((x.shape[0], ), np.int64)
    max_inds = np.zeros((x.shape[0], ), np.int64)
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        r = rows[i]
        c = cols[i]
        x[r, c]+=1
        if(x[r, c] > max_vals[r]):
            max_vals[r] = x[r, c]
            max_inds[r] = c
    return max_inds
```

And then get the dataframe in the end,

```
ans = pd.Series(c[max_columns_after_add_at], r)
```

So, the difference is how we do `argmax(axis=1) after np.add.at()`.

**Timing analysis**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
m = 100000
n = 100000
rows = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = m, size=10000)
cols = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = n, size=10000)
```

So this:

```
%%time
x = np.zeros((m,n))
np.add.at(x, (rows, cols), 1)
maxs = x.argmax(1)
```

gives:

> CPU times: user 12.4 s, sys: 38 s, total: 50.4 s Wall time: 50.5 s

And this

```
%%time
x = np.zeros((m,n))
maxs2 = add_at(x, rows, cols, 1)
```

gives

> CPU times: user 108 ms, sys: 39.4 s, total: 39.5 s Wall time: 38.4 s

Answer (score 1):

Most of the test results discussed in other answers are skewed due to measuring using a trivially small test DataFrame as input. Pandas has some fixed but generally negligible setup time, but it will appear significant next to processing this tiny dataset.

On a larger dataset, the fastest method is using `pd.Series.mode()` with `agg()`:

```py
df.groupby('name')['color'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

Test bench:

```py
arr = np.array([
    ('John',   1,   'White'),
    ('John',   2,  'White'),
    ('John',   3,   'Blue'),
    ('John',   4,   'Blue'),
    ('John',   5,   'White'),
    ('Tom',    2,   'White'),
    ('Tom',    3,   'Blue'),
    ('Tom',    4,   'Blue'),
    ('Tom',    5,   'Black'),
    ('Jerry',  1,   'Black'),
    ('Jerry',  2,   'Black'),
    ('Jerry',  4,   'Black'),
    ('Jerry',  5,   'White')],
    dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('day', 'i8'), ('color', 'O')])

from timeit import Timer
from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(arr).sample(100_000, replace=True)

def factorize():
    i, r = pd.factorize(df.name)
    j, c = pd.factorize(df.color)
    n, m = len(r), len(c)

    b = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.int64)

    np.add.at(b, (i, j), 1)
    return pd.Series(c[b.argmax(1)], r)

t_factorize = Timer(lambda: factorize())
t_idxmax = Timer(lambda: df.groupby(['name', 'color']).size().unstack().idxmax(1))
t_aggmode = Timer(lambda: df.groupby('name')['color'].agg(pd.Series.mode))
t_applymode = Timer(lambda: df.groupby('name').color.apply(pd.Series.mode).reset_index(level=1,drop=True))
t_aggcounter = Timer(lambda: df.groupby('name')['color'].agg(lambda c: Counter(c).most_common(1)[0][0]))
t_applycounter = Timer(lambda: df.groupby('name').color.apply(lambda c: Counter(c).most_common(1)[0][0]))
t_itertools = Timer(lambda: pd.Series(
    {x: Counter(z[-1] for z in y).most_common(1)[0][0] for x,y
      in groupby(sorted(df.values.tolist()), key=lambda x: x[0])}))

n = 100
[print(r) for r in (
    f"{t_factorize.timeit(number=n)=}",
    f"{t_idxmax.timeit(number=n)=}",
    f"{t_aggmode.timeit(number=n)=}",
    f"{t_applymode.timeit(number=n)=}",
    f"{t_applycounter.timeit(number=n)=}",
    f"{t_aggcounter.timeit(number=n)=}",
    f"{t_itertools.timeit(number=n)=}",
)]
```

```
t_factorize.timeit(number=n)=1.325189442
t_idxmax.timeit(number=n)=1.0613339019999999
t_aggmode.timeit(number=n)=1.0495010750000002
t_applymode.timeit(number=n)=1.2837302849999999
t_applycounter.timeit(number=n)=1.9432825890000007
t_aggcounter.timeit(number=n)=1.8283823839999993
t_itertools.timeit(number=n)=7.0855046380000015
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to convert the above table into a data frame and try the posted answers, you can use this snippet. Copy paste the table above in the notebook cell like given below, make sure to remove the hyphens

```
l = """name  day  color
John   1   White
John   2   White
John   3   Blue
John   4   Blue
John   5   White
Tom    2   White
Tom    3   Blue
Tom    4   Blue
Tom    5   Black
Jerry  1   Black
Jerry  2   Black
Jerry  4   Black
Jerry  5   White""".split('\n')
```

Now we need to convert this list into a list of tuples.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([tuple(i.split()) for i in l])
headers = df.iloc[0]
new_df  = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=headers)
```

Use new_df now and you can refer the answers above by @piRSquared